# Timeout | Solution for Fetching YouTube Search Results through API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, youtube-api, google-sheets-api

The current implementation of the YouTube search results apps script functions effectively. However, a challenge arises when attempting to retrieve results for more than 100 keywords, resulting in a timeout error. Assistance is sought in identifying a viable solution or workaround to address this limitation.

```
const CONFIG = {
  sheetName: "Youtube Data",
  spreadsheetId: "1GolMiGKQQtXoEy1L92q7ZDWlhbftKKKwSOW-RGEeQOQ",
  maxResults: 5,
  videoDuration: "",
  publishedAfter: "2023-05-29T00:00:00Z",
  rangeToClear: 'A2:M',
  startRow: 5,
  imageWidth: 200,
  imageHeight: 150,
};

function youTubeSearchResults() {
  const sheet = getSheet();
  const keywordValues = getKeywordValues();
  const results = searchVideos(keywordValues);
  appendResults(sheet, results);
  }

function getSheet() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(CONFIG.sheetName);
  if (!sheet) {
    throw new Error(`Sheet not found: ${CONFIG.sheetName}`);
  }
  return sheet;
}

function getKeywordValues() {
  const source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(CONFIG.spreadsheetId);
  if (!source) {
    throw new Error(`Spreadsheet not found: ${CONFIG.spreadsheetId}`);
  }
  const keywordRange = source.getRange("A2:A" + source.getLastRow());
  const keywordValues = keywordRange.getDisplayValues().filter(([a]) => a);
  return keywordValues;
}

function searchVideos(keywordValues) {
  const sheet = getSheet();
  sheet.getRange(CONFIG.rangeToClear).clearContent();
  const results = [];
  keywordValues.forEach(([keyword]) => {
    const apiUrl = `https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/search?part=snippet&q=${keyword}&maxResults=${CONFIG.maxResults}&type=video&order=viewCount&publishedAfter=${CONFIG.publishedAfter}`;
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl);
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
      const searchResults = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());Logger.log(searchResults)
      const videoResults = searchResults.items.filter(sr => sr.id.kind === "youtube#video");
      const rowResults = videoResults.map(sr => [keyword, sr.id.videoId, `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${sr.id.videoId}`, sr.snippet.title, sr.snippet.publishedAt, sr.snippet.channelTitle, sr.snippet.channelId, `https://www.youtube.com/channel/${sr.snippet.channelId}`, sr.snippet.thumbnails.high.url]);
      if (rowResults.length > 0) {
        results.push(...rowResults);
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error(`YouTube API error: ${response.getResponseCode()}`);
    }
  });
  
  return results;
}

function appendResults(sheet, results) {
  const batchSize = 1000;
  const rows = results.length;
  const iterations = Math.ceil(rows / batchSize);
  for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    const startRow = i * batchSize;
    const endRow = (i + 1) * batchSize;
    const valuesRange = results.slice(startRow, endRow);
    if (valuesRange.length > 0) {
      sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, valuesRange.length, valuesRange[0].length).setValues(valuesRange);
    }
  }
}

function secondPhase() {  
  removeDuplicateRows();
  viewAndSubCount();
  sortSheet();
  formatData();
  compareFormula();
  imageFormula();
}


function removeDuplicateRows() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(CONFIG.sheetName);

  if (sheet) {
    // Get the range of data in the sheet, excluding the header row.
    const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange().offset(1, 0).getValues();

    // Create an object to keep track of unique video IDs.
    const uniqueIds = {};

    // Loop through each row of data in reverse order and keep track of unique video IDs.
    for (let i = dataRange.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      const videoId = dataRange[i][1];
      if (!uniqueIds[videoId]) {
        uniqueIds[videoId] = true;
      } else {
        // If the video ID already exists in the object, remove the row.
        sheet.deleteRow(i + 2); // Add 2 to account for the header row and 0-based indexing.
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.error("Sheet not found.");
  }
}



function viewAndSubCount() {
  // 1. Retrieve the video URLs from Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(CONFIG.sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("B2:B" + sheet.getLastRow());


  // 2. Retrieve the video IDs.
  const values = range.getValues().map(([a]) => a.split("=").pop().trim());Logger.log(values)
  const check = values.slice();


  const limit = 50;
  const obj = [...Array(Math.ceil(values.length / limit))].reduce((obj, _) => {


    // 3. Retrieve the channel IDs and view counts from the video IDs.
    const videoIds = values.splice(0, limit).join(',');
    const res1 = YouTube.Videos.list(["id", "snippet", "statistics"], { id: videoIds, maxResults: CONFIG.maxResults }).items.reduce((o, { id, snippet: { channelId }, statistics: { viewCount, subscriberCount } }) => {
      o[id] = { viewCount: Number(viewCount), subscriberCount: Number(subscriberCount), channelId };
      return o;
    }, {});


    // 4. Retrieve the values of subscriberCount from the channel IDs.
    const res2 = YouTube.Channels.list(["statistics"], { id: Object.values(res1).map(e => e.channelId), maxResults: CONFIG.maxResults }).items.reduce((o, { id, statistics: { subscriberCount } }) => {
      o[id] = Number(subscriberCount);
      return o;
    }, {});


    // 5. Create an object containing view count and subscriber count for each video.
    Object.entries(res1).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      obj[k] = { viewCount: v.viewCount, subscriberCount: res2[v.channelId] ? res2[v.channelId] : "", channelId: v.channelId };
    });


    return obj;
  }, {});


  // 6. Put the values of view count and subscriber count to Spreadsheet.
  range.offset(0, 9).setValues(check.map(a => [obj[a] ? obj[a].viewCount : ""]));
  range.offset(0, 10).setValues(check.map(a => [obj[a] ? obj[a].subscriberCount : ""]));
}


function formatBothColumns() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(CONFIG.sheetName);
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const newData = [];


  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const row = data[i];
    // Skip the first row (header row)
    if (i === 0) {
      newData.push(row);
      continue;
    }
    // Check column J for values less than 1000 and column K for values greater than 5000
    if (row[9] >= 1000 && row[10] <= 5000) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }


  // Clear existing data and write new data
  sheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}

     

function getImages() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(CONFIG.sheetName);
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (let i = CONFIG.startRow - 1; i < lastRow - 1; i++) {
    let url = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 9).getValue();
    let image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(url).build();
    try {
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 9).setValue(image);
      sheet.setRowHeight(i + 1, CONFIG.imageHeight);
      sheet.setColumnWidth(9, CONFIG.imageWidth);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    }
  }
}

function sortSheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(CONFIG.sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  var headerRows = 1; // number of header rows
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(headerRows + 1, 1, numRows - headerRows, numCols); // range excluding header rows
  dataRange.sort({column: 11, ascending: false});
}


function formatData() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(CONFIG.sheetName);
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const newData = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const row = data[i];
    // Skip the first row (header row)
    if (i === 0) {
      newData.push(row);
      continue;
    }
    // Check column K for values less than 5000 or empty cells
    if (row[10] === '' || row[10] > 5000) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }

  // Clear existing data and write new data
  sheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}

function compareFormula() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(CONFIG.sheetName);
  var formula = '=IF(ROW()>ROW(INDEX(D:D,MAX(D:D<>""))),ArrayFormula(ISNUMBER(MATCH(F2:F,Mix!G2:G,0))))';
  var cell = sheet.getRange('M2');
  cell.setFormula(formula);
}


function imageFormula() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(CONFIG.sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  // Apply formula to column J starting from row 2
  var formulaJ = "=ArrayFormula(IMAGE(I2))";
  var columnJ = sheet.getRange("J2:J" + range.getLastRow());
  columnJ.setFormula(formulaJ);

}
```

Comment: Use less keywords (I can't imagine why you'd ever need to use 100) or increase the service tier of your account.

Comment: `const apiUrl = \`https://yt.lemnoslife.com/...` - I doubt that is an in any way "official" API to begin with, this appears to be some 3rd-party data provider? If they have limits set on how often you can make a request to _their_ endpoint, you will have to talk to them about that.

Comment: https://yt.lemnoslife.com owner here, as described in [this issue](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/165) we are experiencing high latencies issues, in addition to [disruption of service](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/166#issuecomment-1559679195). Concerning the no-key service, use [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint if you don't want to be limited by our instances.